# Log in test failing with Devise and Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, devise

I'm using Devise for user Authentication and have the following failing Cucumber scenario:

```
Scenario: Log in to the system
  Given a user called "test" with a password of "secret"
  And I am not logged in # Just visits /users/sign_out
  When I go to the log in page
  And I fill in "user_username" with "test" 
  And I fill in "user_password" with "secret"
  And I press "Sign in"
  Then I should see "Signed in successfully."
```

If I stick a "Then show me the page" at the end I'm shown a page with a blank log in form.

The following (very similar) test works:

```
Scenario: Fail to log in with invalid credentials
  Given a user called "test" with a password of "secret"
  And I am not logged in
  When I go to the log in page
  And I fill in "user_username" with "test" 
  And I fill in "user_password" with "invalid password"
  And I press "Sign in"
  Then I should see "Invalid email or password."
```

... so I'm assuming that the log in does a redirect after a successful validation that Cucumber isn't following (FWIW the log in all works when I do it manually in the browser)... can anyone tell me how to get the test to pass?

Thanks,
Ash

EDIT: It's the last step that is failing with an "expected #has_content?("Signed in successfully.") to return true, got false" error (...ahem... should have mentioned that before!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! I've just loaded my server with the test environment and reproduced the problem.

I'm using ldap_authenticatable with config.ldap_create_user = true. On the first log in the user account is created if it doesn't exist (which it doesn't in the freshly wiped test db), however this is then redirecting back to the log in page rather than following the root route. Subsequent log ins perform the expected behaviour. So the following test passes:

```
Scenario: Log in to the system
  Given a user called "test" with a password of "secret"
  And I am not logged in
  When I go to the log in page
  And I fill in "user_username" with "test" 
  And I fill in "user_password" with "secret"
  And I press "Sign in"
  And I fill in "user_username" with "test" 
  And I fill in "user_password" with "secret"
  And I press "Sign in"
  Then I should see "Signed in successfully."
```

Many thanks to pjammer for the rubber ducking!

Comment: And sure enough it's an issue on the ldap_authenticatable page: https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/issues#issue/3

Comment: if only there was a way to thank me with stack overflow points... :-)

Comment: Was just looking at that - I've just +1'd everything you've said... can't think of any other way to award points! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

is the id field `user_username` or is it `user_email` or something?

Also what does When I go to the log in page look like? you sure you go there?

Comment: Yes they are the field ids. I don't think its a problem in that area though - the other test is passing so I know they are being filled in correctly for that to work. The "When I go to the log in page" is a Capybara step with "the log in page" added in paths.rb. Again, don't think that's the problem - I can't get away from that page hence it showing up in the "show me the page"!

Comment: and test user with secret (i know you obfuscated) but that fixture or factory exists too?

Comment: that's actually an empty step - I'm authenticating against an LDAP server and I know that user exists. It all works swimmingly if I follow the steps manually in the browser. It's just the last step fails. (Actually just realised I should have made that clear! My Bad.. editing now!)